# Arabic and greek inline text in russian document pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, babel, greek, arabic, russian

I'm quite new to Latex. Maybe this can be easily solved, but I could not find the solution.

I'm trying to make document in Russian language with Arabic and Greek inline text in pdflatex. But it keeps erroring out

```
\documentclass[a5paper, oneside, draft]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LAE,LFE,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[arabic,greek,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Первый}
Текст на руском языке с греческим \foreignlanguage{greek}{τέλεσμα} 
и арабским \foreignlanguage{arabic}{ارتداء‎}

\end{document}
```

The errors I get:

```
LaTeX Error: Command \CYRP unavailable in encoding OT1. [\chapter{Первый}]
LaTeX Error: Command \cyre unavailable in encoding OT1. [\chapter{Первый}]
```

If I put `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` under babel declaration, I get error:

```
LaTeX Error: Option clash for package inputenc. [\usepackage]
LaTeX Error: Command \dhal unavailable in encoding OT1. [\chapter{Первый}]
```

Is there a way I can have inline Arabic and Greek inside main Russian text?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to use `pdflatex`, then I would use `arabtex` for the Arabic. Note that `arabtex` uses the old deprecated font commands (e.g., `\rm`, `\it`), so they need to be enabled in `scrbook`.

```
\documentclass[a5paper, oneside, draft, enabledeprecatedfontcommands]{scrbook}
\usepackage[greek,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}
\setcode{utf8}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Первый}
Текст на руском языке с греческим \foreignlanguage{greek}{τέλεσμα} 
и арабским \RL{ارتداء}.
\end{document}
```

[image: pdflatex output]

However, I would choose to use `lualatex` with `babel` for everything instead, which gives you complete control over fonts and much more interesting options.

```
\documentclass[a5paper, oneside, draft]{scrbook}
\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import,language=Default,main]{russian}
\babelprovide[import,language=Default]{greek}
\babelprovide[import,language=Default]{arabic}
\babelfont{rm}{Noto Serif}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Noto Naskh Arabic}
\babelfont{sf}{Noto Sans}
\babelfont[arabic]{sf}{Noto Sans Arabic}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Первый}
Текст на руском языке с греческим \foreignlanguage{greek}{τέλεσμα} 
и арабским \foreignlanguage{arabic}{ارتداء}.
\end{document}
```

[image: lualatex output]