# Add an Arab Word within an English Document

Tags: arabic, arabtex

I need to add an Arab word (قرار) to an English LaTex document.
I played around with:

```
\usepackage{arabtex}
```

which seems to require that I transliterate the word like this:

```
 \<salAm>
```

However, unfortunately, I do not know how to transliterate the given word.

I have found solutions that require to switch the typesetting engine to "xelatex" or "lualatex".
However, I am on Overleaf and I do not know whether this is possible there.

Comment: Try the button "Menu" (top left corner on overleaf) and change compiler to XeLaTeX for your XeLaTeX solution.

Comment: It is possible to use LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX in overleaf. You can specify which engine you want somewhere in the project settings. See https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Changing_compiler. I think the LuaLaTeX with `babel` is probably the best solution, unless you have font shaping issues, then you're stuck with XeLaTeX for the moment. This answer shows how to use both `arabtex` and `lualatex` for a similar document, but with Russian as the main language. Does that help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/480017/87678

Comment: If you want to use transliteration instead of utf8 entry for Arabic, then I think [this manual](http://129.69.218.213/arabtex/doc/arabdoc.pdf) helps. But I can't read Arabic to know.

Comment: Thank you @DavidPurton, the link was very helpful in order to find out the answer for this particular problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple way (while sticking with pdfLaTeX) is as follows

```
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{utf8}
\setcode{utf8}
```

and then in the text:

```
\RL{قرار}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that it doesn't work in case you're using the dmath environment.